# Nginx - Allow only specific IPs or specific URL path to skip authentication

Tags: centos, nginx

I have nginx configuration that looks like this:

```
location / {
    satisfy any;
    allow SOME_IP_ADDRESS;
    allow SOME_IP_ADDRESS;
    allow SOME_IP_ADDRESS;
    deny all;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file SOME_PATH/.htpasswd;
    include   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}

location ~ .php$ {
    satisfy any;
    allow SOME_IP_ADDRESS;
    allow SOME_IP_ADDRESS;
    allow SOME_IP_ADDRESS;
    deny all;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file SOME_PATH/.htpasswd;
    add_header X-UA-Compatible 'IE=Edge,chrome=1';
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

The current result is that only the listed IPs can access the website without authentication.
I want to keep it that way, but also allow everyone skip the authorization if the requested URI contains a specific string.
For example: Anyone who enters domain.com/...SOME-STRING... can skip the authorization.
-- Any Idea?

Comment: What you probably want is to use a regular expression to match the contents of the $uri variable.  You should be able to put the auth stuff in an `if` block that matches $uri if the string you want isn't present.

Comment: I tried to do that in a few ways & it lead to errors on nginx restart saying stuff like "auth is not allowed in here" etc... could you please give me an example of the right way to do that?  thanks.